# Can a div be created to act like a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using jquery to populate a dropdown menu from a text file and it is working fine.  But visually, I would like it to look different.

My dropdown is in a div.  What I would like to do is make the div itself clickable so that when you click it, the dropdown menu options pop up.  And when an option is selected, the div's label is set to the text of the selected option.

Is there someway to make the dropdown menu hidden but still functional?

[image]

Comment: Yup.  Lots of ways.  Unfortunately, your question is way too broad.  Try looking for form input dropdown plugins in google.

Comment: are you just talking about html select element

Comment: There are a million ways to do this; too broad for Stack Overflow, but a quick search will reveal lots of plugins and guides for doing it yourself.

Comment: This is a broad question. Maybe you're looking to style the `select` element to your liking and act as it normally does. Try searching for that.

Comment: @Muhammad Umer Yes, an html select element

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want this.
Click here for a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K66nN/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2">Sign in with
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter icon-large"></i>Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-github icon-large"></i>Github</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook icon-large"></i>Facebook</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*,*:after,*:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 15px;

    /* Styles */
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid grey;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-2:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey transparent;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown {
  /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: -45px;
    right: 0px;

    /* Styles */
    background: white;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    list-style: none;

    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    border-left: 5px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li:nth-child(1) a { 
    border-left-color: #00ACED;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li:nth-child(2) a {
    border-left-color: #4183C4;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li:nth-child(3) a {
    border-left-color: #3B5998;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li i {
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Hover state */

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li:hover a {
    color: grey;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-2.active:after {
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents : function() {
    var obj = this;
    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    }); 
  }
}
$(function() {
  var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
    $(document).click(function() {
      $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: i will create for you this demo i hopefully be useful [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL5HD/)

Answer (score 4):

Here take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zw32/

Basically you can select which div is selected by searching for div with class selected and you could assign data attribute to get additional value.

**Css**

```
* { margin: 0;  padding: 0; }

.sel {
    color:white;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #55E6FA;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.txt { padding: 10px; }
.selected { background-color: #31A9B9; }
.hide { display: none; }
.sel .options div:hover { background-color: #31A9B9; }

.sel .options {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #66f7FB;
}
.sel .options div {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
var sel = $('.sel'),
    txt = $('.txt'),
    options = $('.options');

sel.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    options.show();
});

$('body').click(function (e) {
    options.hide();
});

options.children('div').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    txt.text($(this).text());
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('div').removeClass('selected');
    options.hide();
});
```

Comment: This should work.  But if I was using Objects to give my select options a JSON value, how can I get the functionality to be like a dropdown where I can do something with the selected option?

Comment: To answer my own question, I think I can assign the same object values to the li value attribute.