# Drop down similar to select tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create an drop down that should act like, similar to select tag.

**Drop down**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span>value 01</span>
    <span>value 02</span>
    <span>value 03</span>
</div>
```

**Select**

```
<select>
    <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
    <option>03</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nothing, just couldn't found any solution/idea of how to do it.

Comment: Have you even tried searching on google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374678/can-a-div-be-created-to-act-like-a-dropdown

Comment: Yes I did, but wasn't got any particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link for reference.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coma/9KvhL/25/)

```
 <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Size
        <span class="caret"></span>

    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>16</li>
        <li>17</li>
        <li>18</li>
        <li>19</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like Chosen :

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

or create your own stylesheet.