# hrefs with anchor scroll inside a dropdown

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a drop-down like so:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="i in sc.cl" value="{{i.deptname"}}><a ng-href="#{{i.id}}">{{i.deptname}}</a></option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Basically, the dropdown element's name is inside an array and there are divs inside the html having the id as i.id like this:

```
<div class="right-bar">
                <section class="contact-block" ng-repeat="i in sc.cl" id="{{i.id}}">
                    <div class="description">{{i.deptname}}</div>
                    <div class="inner-block">
                        <div ng-repeat="j in i.cgs">
                            <img class="vertical-image" src="frame.png">
                            <img class="horizontal-image" src="mobileframe.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
```

whenever I click the dropdown element, I want it to scroll to the particular section. But nothing happens when I do so. Why does this happen? And when I tried inspect element in chrome, it doesn't even show the  tags in the ng-repeat dropdown.

Comment: I don't think you need to use that interpolation in the `ng-href` directive, i.e. try `ng-href="i.id"`

Comment: @wilusdaman that did not work. Whats weird is, when I used inspect element on chrome, it didn't even show the <a> tag

Comment: Gotcha. That doesn't surprise me; inputs aren't really meant for purposes like this. I'd encourage you to use a list-based dropdown for more consistent behavior. If you're using a css library, it will almost certainly provide you with one, and if not, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374678/can-a-div-be-created-to-act-like-a-dropdown) out

Answer (score 0):

You should use Angular's `$anchorScroll`.

Please, take a look at this similar question: [How to handle anchor hash linking in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/how-to-handle-anchor-hash-linking-in-angularjs)

Comment: This worked when I used <li> and <ul> but does not work inside an <option> tag.

Comment: How did you do it? The `<option>` tag should have a `ng-click` attribute, which would call the controller method responsible for the anchor navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhm, my suggestion seems completely unrelated as I'm a dummy at AngularJS. But I have a solution to scrolling to a section using jQuery. You could simply give the section an ID and animate scrolling to that point on click by calculating the top offset and animating the scrolltop to that point...If you want me to show you the code, I'll gladly do so...:-) (Oh and I know this should be a comment because it doesn't directly answer the question, but my reputation's 13 so I can't comment)...