# Is it possible to put a check box inside a DropDownList that uses DataSourceID?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to put a check box inside a DropDownList, but all I find is examples that the DropDownList uses ListItem, something like:

```
<asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:ListItem/>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

But the code I'm using doesn't have the ListItem:

```
<asp:DropDownList DataSourceID="example"> </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now how can I make the DropDownList appear with Check Boxes?

Comment: No it is not possible. You need to create something yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374678/can-a-div-be-created-to-act-like-a-dropdown

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin for asp.net here that looks to be rather nice - http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop down list is not available for multi select. What I suggest is to use a `asp:ListBox` with `SelectionMode="Multiple"` from what you get on page convert it to a drop down multi select list.

I suggest `asp:ListBox` because you can use your `DataSource`.

so for example if you have

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"  SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="200px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

and use a plugin like [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), or the  [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://www.codehim.com/demo/bootstrap-multiselect-dropdown/) you can have what you search for.

**The key here is to use the ListBox with multiselect.**

Answer (score -1):

Short of writing your own dropdown the closest you will probably come is to include an emoji at the start of each option text. Then toggle this from say a ⭕ to a  when selected